# VBA I can't work Exists method with Dictionary

Tags: vba, excel

[image: pivot table]

```
Dim memberDic As Object: Set memberDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set memberDic("Team A") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

memberDic("Team A")("Tanaka") = 1
memberDic("Team A")("Watanabe") = 2
memberDic("Team A")("Shimizu") = 3

For Each person In ActiveSheet.PivotTables(fy).PivotFields("name").PivotItems
    If Not memberDic("Team A").Exists(person.Name) Then
        'hidden person except Team A
    End If
Next person
```

I'd like to excluse item with Exists method.
Could you give me advice?

Comment: You need to show how your  instantiate the Dictionary objects.

Comment: i postscripted at first line in code. Is "Scripting Dictionary" a cause?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me.  `//` is not a valid VBA comment use the single quote `'` instead.

Comment: You may want to trim the values. `If Not memberDic("Team A").Exists(Trim(person.Name)) Then`

Comment: memberDic("Team A").Add Trim(Cells(i, j)), num <- I worked out like this way!!  Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: Your welcome.  You should post and accept your answer when you are allowed to.

Comment: If you have a lot more coding related to PivotTables, you might define and set relevant `PivotTable` objects like also `PivotCache`, `PivotField`, etc.

Comment: have you tried referencing the Scripting library?

Answer (score 0):

Formalising a comment that was posted for the question:

Trim the value from the pivot table so that the Exists works correctly:

```
For Each person In ActiveSheet.PivotTables(fy).PivotFields("name").PivotItems
    If Not memberDic("Team A").Exists(Trim(person.Name)) Then
        'hidden person except Team A
    End If
Next person
```